# AJAX request accepts hard-coded JSON, but not soft-coded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This AJAX request returns 'success' if the output in PHP is copied and pasted JSON, but 'fail' if it's generated by the file. Have a look at the comments in api.php below to see what I mean.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

api.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$jsonurl = "http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q=st+pancras&f=js";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

// THIS DOESN'T WORK (RETURNS 'FAIL')
print_r($json);
?>

<!-- THIS WORKS (RETURNS 'SUCCESS') -->
{"results": { "constituencies": [{"constituency_name": "Holborn and St Pancras", "member_name": "Frank Dobson", "member_party": "Labour", "member_biography_url": "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/Frank-Dobson/180", "member_website": "", "uri": "http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/constituencies/holborn-and-st-pancras.json" } ], "members": [] }}
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Bang on, write it up and I'll accept.

Comment: I suspect you didn't really see what output the PHP script generates ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
echo $json;
```

not

```
print_r($json);
```

`$json` is a string, so you just want to print it, which is what `echo` does.

[`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) on the other hand:

> Prints human-readable information about a variable

The moral of the story:  Look at the output of your PHP script.  Test *pieces* and verify that each piece is working, instead of trying to test the entire system.